# Catch Record Source Error Before Form Load - Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently working on a form in access whose Record Source is supposed to be from a Temporary Table that should be generated at `Form_Load()` and deleted when the form is closed.

The way I have it working now is that the Record Source is set to another permanant table, and when the form loads, the temporary table is generated and the record source is changed. When the form is closed, the code sets the Record Source back to whatever it was originally. This works pretty well.

However, occassionally something goes wrong, and for one reason or another, the Record Source property doesn't get switched back, though the temp table is deleted so when I try to load the form, I get the error:

> The record source 'TempTable' specified on this form or report does not exist

It turns out that this error occurs even before `Form_Load()` is called so I can't prepare for it before hand. The only way I can think of fixing this is trying to reset it when a button on my Home form is pressed, however this isn't optimal, since I still want to be able to open it from other locations.

Is there any way to catch this error and fix it without having to go into the form properties and change the record source any time something goes wrong?

Comment: You are looking at really serious bloat if you do this. Tables should not be created and deleted in this way. Can you not, as a minimum, empty the table and repopulate it? This is still much less than an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Workaround would be not to call/ Open the form but a function.
The Function would ba able to Arrange all recordsource work. Once this is done you can Open the form.

In fact you wouldn't need to switch the recorsource of the form anymore.

Function openform()

- Prepare temporary table
- Open Form

End Function

Martin

Comment: That was the workaround I had involving the opening button, though as I mentioned, I want the form to be opened from numerous locations, including the Access Sidebar and several other buttons and functions.

As far as I know, I can't run functions from the Access Sidebar and I'd rather not be repeating myself for every button that opens the form, which is why I wanted to know if I could catch it in the opening of the form itself.